# How do I protest a duplicate question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I feel that two people incorrectly marked my question as a duplicate. 
[How to write large binary data fast in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112296/how-to-write-large-binary-data-fast-in-java)

On its face, my question is about large amounts of binary data, not just opening a file and writing text.

I feel like I should have some way to protest, without simply editing my own question.

Answer (score 7):

> I feel like I should have some way to protest, without simply editing my own question.

There is not. Editing a closed question will put it in the review queue where other users judge whether it should be reopened. That is just the way it works.

If there is a case of serious misuse of moderation powers, moderators can step in, but that doesn't seem to apply here. Flagging is what you should do in such case.

So this is what you should do: edit your question and explain why the duplicate doesn't apply, or where it doesn't cover your edge cases. Then it has a good chance of getting reopened.